# Compute identical hash of near identical images

Tags: image, similarity

Different browser render images in different ways. Is there a kind of smooth-algorithm to make them identical. I tried different filters median, pixelate, avarage, etc with no luck.

You can find an example (chrome vs ie) and a comparison i did with imagemagick.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9AFP7Wrq30xc0NUSlZPQnA3ZU0&usp=sharing

Thanks.

ps:
the fact is that i want to get some information server-side (on a different server) that is related to the image (jpg). i could transmit the whole image, but it's not practical. So I was thinking to compute a sha512 of the image client-side and retrieve the info by that. I hope i'm clearer.

Comment: The computing hashes approach is not going to help. If there is one bit difference between the images, then the hashes will be completely different. Hashes, especially 'cryptographic' ones, are designed to be very different given similar input.Something you may find useful, as regards finding 'similar images' is this: The Puzzle library is designed to quickly find visually similar images (gif, png, jpg), even if they have been resized, recompressed, recolored or slightly modified. I have no idea as to the value of it

Comment: You are absolutely right. I don't know php very well and the algorithm of PuzzleLib is not very well described. Do you know how it works?

Comment: Thi is beyond my field of expertise, however, you may find it useful: [project/libpuzzle/doc](http://www.pureftpd.org/project/libpuzzle/doc)